# Is SVG really scalable :)?

Tags: animation, svg

Good use for SVG in websites would be to cheaply scale graphics and backgrounds to full screensize. Then why is my CPU going berserk when scaling up my simple SVG-animation to full screen. SVG is vectors and sould take same time to calculate regardless scale ?

Comment: Do you have an example of the SVG causing the high CPU usage?

Comment: See Robert Longson comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SVG is powerful and rich in animation and quality when you resize in any size, from smaller to bigger. It never loses the quality. It is superior to the ICNS, JPG and PNG formats. But not all browsers are compatible with the SVG paths. I recommend you to use Inkscape, the which uses the SVG as SVG standard, do all the separated paths.

As for the CPU, it depends on your and their computers and browsers specifications. An inexpert user of Windows 7 and internet Explorer 9 couldn't see your SVG. Always consult http://caniuse.com (it has SVG list) in the which each browser is compatible with each SVG feature.

Comment: The question is about why SVG (when animated) uses so much resources in large scale compared to small. Its almost you could use canvas insted.

Comment: How much size of SVG file? Can you send it to me that I analyse it on my computer?

Comment: THX Gustavo. See Robert Longson comment, there is the explonation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: **Yes**, SVG is really scalable.

As for your CPU freaking out, that depends on several variables, including your computer specs, what browser you're using, and how complex the SVG is. Of course, it could also be something like a driver issue, etc.

Comment: Maybe not the best heading but still wondering why it takes so much  CPU when running a very simple animation on large scale. Is it about repainting. As far as i know browsers cant repaint only specific area ?!

Comment: @triver I have just posted an answer in the which I gave you a link that tells which SVG feature is compatible with each browser.

Comment: @triver browsers certainly can and do [repaint only specific areas](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:DisplayListBasedInvalidation#Display_List_Invalidation).

Comment: Thanks Robert! Then it´s just normal behavior.